# Is this a Prima Facie case for State Tax Fraud?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

Manafort has been convicted of Federal Tax Fraud. Does that conviction form the basis for a prima facie case of state level tax fraud?

While the President has authority to pardon the federal crime, he is apparently not able to pardon for state crimes. Even in light of a possible federal pardon, is Manafort still in significant legal jeopardy with state tax fraud charges.

Answer (score 2):

As in most other states, [New York law](https://codes.findlaw.com/ny/tax-law/tax-sect-611.html) uses federal AGI as the starting point for calculating state tax liability. If a taxpayer's federal AGI is fraudulent, his state taxes would presumably be fraudulent as well. A federal pardon would have no effect on his liability for crimes at the state level.

Comment: Could the federal conviction *itself* be used as evidence in state court?  Or would the state prosecutors need to prove the case from scratch, possibly using some or all of the same evidence from the federal trial?

Comment: If it were a civil tax enforcement action, NY Evidence Rule 8.35 suggests it could be used. I don't know New York evidence well enough to say how that would work in a criminal case.

Answer (score -1):

The state would still have to prove any possible criminal violations beyond a reasonable doubt.

The Manafort case involved a lot of overseas activity and the related federal regulations which may not be applicable at the state level. It's even possible his state filings are accurate. Unlikely but certainly possible. Many states, possibly all of them, don't include a requirement to declare foreign accounts for example.

In short, no it wouldn't be indisputable evidence of guilt for state tax law violations. If his state returns are incorrect though and he fails to correct them, it would certainly be strong evidence of intent though.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding prima facia when you say "no".  Prima Facia simply means "raise a presumption unless disproved or rebutted".

Comment: When is anyone presumed to have committed a crime?

Comment: And while you are correct that state law may not tax overseas activities, because NY requires the declaration of Federal AGI on the state form, the two better match. If, (for example) overseas activities are not taxable on the state return those would be backed-out later in the state return.

Comment: Sure but that alone isn't enough to shift the burden of proof onto the defendant.

Comment: When is anyone presumed..... Everyday !  People are charged everyday by law enforcement.

Comment: burden of proof  .... ever had a tax audit?  The tax payer is required to "show proof"  Ever been to tax court?  Again the tax payer is required to substantiate the validity and truthfulness of their tax return.

Comment: I was assuming this was referring to criminal liability since it specifically mentioned Manafort. Conviction for a federal crime alone certainly wouldn't be enough to let a state presume someone is guilty. An auditor? Sure, but they would still have to present an alternative amount somewhere on the return. Using the federal AGI as reported in a fraudulent return may still end up with no changes if, for whatever reason, certain amounts were just not included instead of backed out in the return.

Comment: Seriously, haven't you read the Signature assertion on your tax return?  If not it says: "Under penalties of perjury, I declare that I have examined this return and accompanying schedules and statements, and to the best of my knowledge and belief, they are true, correct and accurately list all amounts and sources of income I received during the tax year."  The taxpayer is asserting that EVERYTHING listed is accurate, regardless.

Comment: Is there even a jurat on the NY return? Even assuming there is, the language you used would likely be unenforceable and is often used as a scare tactic. But, even assuming the language you used is valid, inaccurate doesn't mean the same as matches exactly. If the only difference is adjustments were made in line rather than in a subsequent statement, calling for a criminal conviction is over the line. Plus, how would you allow for amending returns if it means 'admitting' the first one you swore was accurate actually wasn't?

Comment: You gone way past commenting and into arguing. If you actually want an answer to your question, I suggest you post a question.

Comment: I just enjoy discussing tax issues, lol but I'll certainly contribute if I think of a good question